# How can I make my vertical navigation bar horizontal

Tags: html, css

I recently made a vertical navigation bar and was wondering how I could make it horizontal and make it display in the same sized boxes equally spaced apart

I have tried to float text to the left but that doesn't work as well as followed W3 School tutorial on creating a horizontal navigation bar. W3 School isn't useful. I am a HTML and CSS newbie.

```css
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100px;
  border: 1px solid;
}

li a {
  display: block;
  color: #000000;
  padding: 8px 16px;
  text-decoration: none; 
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid;
}

li:last-child a {
  border-bottom: none; 
}

li a:hover {
  background-color:red;
  color:white; 
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
  <li><a href="services.html">Services</a></li>
  <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">LinkedIn</a></li>
</ul>
```

I expect a horizontal navigation bar that is centred and equally spaced apart in the same sized boxes that appear.

Answer (score 0):

Start changing display property and add it to `li` element like the following snippet. You must play with the values and the properties to achieve what you need.

```css
ul {
  font-size: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 1px solid;
}
ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  list-style-type: none;
  width: 20%;
  font-size: 1rem;
}
li a {
  color: #000000;
  padding: 8px 16px;
  text-decoration: none; 
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid;
}

li:last-child a {
  border-bottom: none; 
}

li a:hover {
  background-color:red;
  color:white; 
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
  <li><a href="services.html">Services</a></li>
  <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">LinkedIn</a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score -1):

Use `flex`. You can read more about it [here](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_flexbox.asp).

```css
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  width: 400px;
  border: 1px solid;
}

li a {
  display: block;
  color: #000000;
  padding: 8px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid;
}

li:last-child a {
  border-bottom: none;
}

li a:hover {
  background-color: red;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
  <li><a href="services.html">Services</a></li>
  <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">LinkedIn</a></li>
</ul>
```